# .checked always returns true?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using vanilla js, and I'm stumped because there's very little code here, so I'm not sure where the problem lies. It may be a misunderstanding on my part on how the attribute works.

```js
function changeState() {
 const self = event.target
 const parent = event.path[1]
 
 if (self.type == "radio") {
  console.log(self.id + " is " + self.checked)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="usernames_buttons">
  <input type="radio" name="usernames" id="usernames-bl" onclick="changeState()" checked>
    <label for="usernames-bl">BL</label>
  </input>
  <input type="radio" name="usernames" id="usernames-wl" onclick="changeState()">
    <label for="usernames-wl">WL</label>
  </input>
  <button data-toggle onclick="changeState()">OFF</button>
</div>
```

I paired everything down to just this code and ran it in a code pen to test, and the console.log will return true regardless of which option I am clicking. The expectation is that usernames-bl would return true and -wl would return false, but they return true whether the checked attribute is there or not.

Comment: You are invoking the changeState() on every click and i guess, as its a radio button, which will always give checked 'true' on click.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware it set the checked attribute before running the callback. I checked the other elements at the same time and it looks like it's functioning like I expected it to, I just wasn't seeing the elements get updated within Chrome's dev tools so I assumed it wasn't working.

Comment: Also, is there anyway you could put that as an answer so I could mark it as the correct one?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `input` cannot have child elements, neither tags nor text nodes. Also, `"message": "TypeError: event.path is undefined"`. Do not use inline event listeners, that is considered really bad practice.

Comment: I pulled the code from what I was working with and tried to remove everything irrelevant. The ```event.path[1]``` was something I missed, it seems like. Also, why is using an inline event listener bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the changeState() on every click and i guess, as its a radio button, which will always give checked 'true' on click

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it right minus the "Off" button should un-check both.. so I added this block:

```
if (self.type != "radio") {
    document.getElementById("usernames-wl").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("usernames-bl").checked = false;
  }
```

```js
function changeState() {
  const self = event.target
  const parent = event.path[1]

  if (self.type != "radio") {
    document.getElementById("usernames-wl").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("usernames-bl").checked = false;
  }
  
  console.log("usernames-wl is " + document.getElementById("usernames-wl").checked)  
  console.log("usernames-bl is " + document.getElementById("usernames-bl").checked)
}
```

```html
<div id="usernames_buttons">
  <input type="radio" name="usernames" id="usernames-bl" onclick="changeState()" checked/>
  <label for="usernames-bl">BL</label>
  <input type="radio" name="usernames" id="usernames-wl" onclick="changeState()"/>
  <label for="usernames-wl">WL</label>
  <button data-toggle onclick="changeState()">OFF</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML is invalid. input cannot have child elements, neither tags nor text nodes.